# Why is the balance of the ethereum account still zero after I create a token based on the private chain I built？

Tags: go-ethereum, solidity, contract-debugging, solc, balances

0
down vote
favorite
I used the contract codes available on the ethereum official website，to create an advanced token on the private chain run in geth console. The version of geth is 1.5.5，and the version of solc is 0.4.8.

My steps are：

1.initialize my geth：`geth init genesis.json` then `geth --networkid 42 --nodiscover --maxpeers 0 console`

2.check the compiler：`eth.getCompilers()` returns：solidity

3.I used the online compiling website to give me the relative abi and code to directly deploy my contract.

I input：

（1）`abi=[{"constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"newSellPrice","type":"uint256"},……` too long to copy the result；

（2）then create the contract：`multiplyContract = web3.eth.contract(abi)`

（3）`multiply= multiplyContract.new(10000,"AKING",2,"AK",0xf32200730fdaca83f18171015c0be2a6342d46c4，{from: primaryAddress, data: 0x+code})`

the first parameter means the initial supply，the second one represents the name of the token, the third one means the decimalUnit，the forth one is the address which can have the initial supply of tokens.

4.check whether my contract has deployed：

I input ：`txpool.status`

then I got：pending：1

5.I began to mine the contract：

input： `miner.start()` and `miner.stop()`

then I input：`eth.getBlock(5319)`

I found that transaction.

6.Interact with my contract：

Input：`MyContract = eth.contract(abi)`

Then：`myContract = MyContract.at(multiply.address)`

Start mining for a while.
The whole process went well, however when I input

`myContract.balanceOf(0xf32200730fdaca83f18171015c0be2a6342d46c4)`

（the address is the eth.account[0]and also the address which possesses the tokens I created. I also tried some other addresses , they all returned to zero. And I also tried some other expressions like `myContract.balanceOf(eth.accounts[0], {from: eth.accounts[0]})` or `myContract.balanceOf.sendTransaction(eth.accounts[0], {from: eth.accounts[0]})`

If I used ：`eth.getBalance(eth.accounts[0])` it only returns the ethers in my account which is not what I want to see.

So，is there anything wrong with my process？ or is there anything important that is missed ？ What‘s the point？

The whole codes are as follows：

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.2;
    contract owned {
    address public owner;

    function owned() {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner {
        if (msg.sender != owner) throw;
        _;
    }

    function transferOwnership(address newOwner) onlyOwner {
        owner = newOwner;
    }
}

contract tokenRecipient { function receiveApproval(address _from, uint256 _value, address _token, bytes _extraData); }

contract token {
    /* Public variables of the token */
    string public standard = 'Token 0.1';
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals;
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    /* This creates an array with all balances */
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

    /* This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients */
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint256 value);

    /* Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract */
    function token(
        uint256 initialSupply,
        string tokenName,
        uint8 decimalUnits,
        string tokenSymbol
        ) {
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = initialSupply;              // Give the creator all initial tokens
        totalSupply = initialSupply;                        // Update total supply
        name = tokenName;                                   // Set the name for display purposes
        symbol = tokenSymbol;                               // Set the symbol for display purposes
        decimals = decimalUnits;                            // Amount of decimals for display purposes
    }

    /* Send coins */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) {
        if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < _value) throw;           // Check if the sender has enough
        if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) throw; // Check for overflows
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;                     // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                            // Add the same to the recipient
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);                   // Notify anyone listening that this transfer took place
    }

    /* Allow another contract to spend some tokens in your behalf */
    function approve(address _spender, uint256 _value)
        returns (bool success) {
        allowance[msg.sender][_spender] = _value;
        tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
        return true;
    }

    /* Approve and then comunicate the approved contract in a single tx */
    function approveAndCall(address _spender, uint256 _value, bytes _extraData)
        returns (bool success) {    
        tokenRecipient spender = tokenRecipient(_spender);
        if (approve(_spender, _value)) {
            spender.receiveApproval(msg.sender, _value, this, _extraData);
            return true;
        }
    }

    /* A contract attempts to get the coins */
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        if (balanceOf[_from] < _value) throw;                 // Check if the sender has enough
        if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) throw;  // Check for overflows
        if (_value > allowance[_from][msg.sender]) throw;   // Check allowance
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                          // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                            // Add the same to the recipient
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    /* This unnamed function is called whenever someone tries to send ether to it */
    function () {
        throw;     // Prevents accidental sending of ether
    }
}

contract MyAdvancedToken is owned, token {

    uint256 public sellPrice;
    uint256 public buyPrice;
    uint256 public totalSupply;

    mapping (address => bool) public frozenAccount;

    /* This generates a public event on the blockchain that will notify clients */
    event FrozenFunds(address target, bool frozen);

    /* Initializes contract with initial supply tokens to the creator of the contract */
    function MyAdvancedToken(
        uint256 initialSupply,
        string tokenName,
        uint8 decimalUnits,
        string tokenSymbol,
        address centralMinter
    ) token (initialSupply, tokenName, decimalUnits, tokenSymbol) {
        if(centralMinter != 0 ) owner = centralMinter;      // Sets the owner as specified (if centralMinter is not specified the owner is msg.sender)
        balanceOf[owner] = initialSupply;                   // Give the owner all initial tokens
    }

    /* Send coins */
    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) {
        if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < _value) throw;           // Check if the sender has enough
        if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) throw; // Check for overflows
        if (frozenAccount[msg.sender]) throw;                // Check if frozen
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= _value;                     // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                            // Add the same to the recipient
        Transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);                   // Notify anyone listening that this transfer took place
    }


    /* A contract attempts to get the coins */
    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) returns (bool success) {
        if (frozenAccount[_from]) throw;                        // Check if frozen            
        if (balanceOf[_from] < _value) throw;                 // Check if the sender has enough
        if (balanceOf[_to] + _value < balanceOf[_to]) throw;  // Check for overflows
        if (_value > allowance[_from][msg.sender]) throw;   // Check allowance
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;                          // Subtract from the sender
        balanceOf[_to] += _value;                            // Add the same to the recipient
        allowance[_from][msg.sender] -= _value;
        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
        return true;
    }

    function mintToken(address target, uint256 mintedAmount) onlyOwner {
        balanceOf[target] += mintedAmount;
        totalSupply += mintedAmount;
        Transfer(0, this, mintedAmount);
        Transfer(this, target, mintedAmount);
    }

    function freezeAccount(address target, bool freeze) onlyOwner {
        frozenAccount[target] = freeze;
        FrozenFunds(target, freeze);
    }

    function setPrices(uint256 newSellPrice, uint256 newBuyPrice) onlyOwner {
        sellPrice = newSellPrice;
        buyPrice = newBuyPrice;
    }

    function buy() payable {
        uint amount = msg.value / buyPrice;                // calculates the amount
        if (balanceOf[this] < amount) throw;               // checks if it has enough to sell
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += amount;                   // adds the amount to buyer's balance
        balanceOf[this] -= amount;                         // subtracts amount from seller's balance
        Transfer(this, msg.sender, amount);                // execute an event reflecting the change
    }

    function sell(uint256 amount) {
        if (balanceOf[msg.sender] < amount ) throw;        // checks if the sender has enough to sell
        balanceOf[this] += amount;                         // adds the amount to owner's balance
        balanceOf[msg.sender] -= amount;                   // subtracts the amount from seller's balance
        if (!msg.sender.send(amount * sellPrice)) {        // sends ether to the seller. It's important
            throw;                                         // to do this last to avoid recursion attacks
        } else {
            Transfer(msg.sender, this, amount);            // executes an event reflecting on the change
        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: As mentioned on Stack Overflow, check if quoting the address helps. See https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#user-content-a-note-on-big-numbers-in-web3js.